# ArrayList outOfBoundsException database error

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist

Hey as I was running tests on my application I began to delete database values from my database. Once I did I began getting this error
`Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0`

It is for this line of code.
`PasswordResults passwordResults = password.get(0);` which I am confused on as `.get(0)` would always get the selected row on my recyclerView prior to me deleting some data in the database.

Here is my code for my `PasswordManager` where I am getting the error at.
I am passing a checker integer and a String that has the selectedID of the row the user clicked. I have tried using `PasswordResults passwordResults = password.get(Integer.parseInt(id))` thinking that would work but it does not.

```
// method to load correct screen based on user input.
    public void loadScreen(int c, String id){
        // checking if it is a previous entry.
        if(c == 1) {
            // Since there already is a password set button to "Show Password"
            password_btn.setText("Show");
            // getting selected passwords data.
            password = db.getSelectedPassword(id);

            // GETTING ERROR HERE
            PasswordResults passwordResults = password.get(0);

            idSelected = id;
            entryName_et.setText(passwordResults.entryName);
            website_et.setText(passwordResults.website);
            username_et.setText(passwordResults.username);

            realPassword = passwordResults.password;
            // dont show real password yet.
            if(showPW == 1)
                password_et.setText(realPassword);
             else 
                password_et.setText("***********");

            desc_et.setText(passwordResults.description);

            // make delete button visible since user could want to delete entry.
            delete_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // since user is creating a new entry dont show delete button.
            delete_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

---

Here is my code for my `Database` class which handles the retrieval of information in my database.

```
public void addPassword(String n, String w, String u, String p, String d) {
    // get database.
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    try {
        // add scores.
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME, n);
        values.put(COLUMN_WEBSITE, w);
        values.put(COLUMN_USERNAME, u);
        values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD, p);
        values.put(COLUMN_DESC, d);

        // insert will handle null values. closing.
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, "", values);
        db.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
}

public void removePassword(String id){
    // get database.
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    // delete database then close or print error.
    try {
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "_id="+id, null);
        db.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
}

public void updatePassword(String id, String n, String w, String u, String p, String d) {
    // get database.
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    //update database then close or print error.
    try {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_ID, id);
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME, n);
        values.put(COLUMN_WEBSITE, w);
        values.put(COLUMN_USERNAME, u);
        values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD, p);
        values.put(COLUMN_DESC, d);
        db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, "_id="+id, null);
        db.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
}

public ArrayList<PasswordResults> getPasswords() {
    // get database, password array, and select statement.
    passwords = new ArrayList<>();
    String refQuery = "Select "+COLUMN_NAME+", "+COLUMN_WEBSITE+", "+COLUMN_USERNAME+", "+COLUMN_PASSWORD+", "+COLUMN_DESC+" FROM "+TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    // link to database
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(refQuery, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            PasswordResults passwordResults = new PasswordResults();
            passwordResults.entryName = cursor.getString(0);
            passwordResults.website = cursor.getString(1);
            passwordResults.username = cursor.getString(2);
            passwordResults.password = cursor.getString(3);
            passwordResults.description = cursor.getString(4);
            passwords.add(passwordResults);
        } while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    return passwords;
}

public ArrayList<PasswordResults> getSelectedPassword(String id) {
    // get database, password array, and select statement.
    passwords = new ArrayList<>();
    String refQuery = "Select "+COLUMN_NAME+", "+COLUMN_WEBSITE+", "+COLUMN_USERNAME+", "+COLUMN_PASSWORD+", "+COLUMN_DESC+" FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+COLUMN_ID+" = "+id;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    // link to database
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(refQuery, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            PasswordResults passwordResults = new PasswordResults();
            passwordResults.id = Integer.parseInt(id);
            passwordResults.entryName = cursor.getString(0);
            passwordResults.website = cursor.getString(1);
            passwordResults.username = cursor.getString(2);
            passwordResults.password = cursor.getString(3);
            passwordResults.description = cursor.getString(4);
            passwords.add(passwordResults);
        } while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    return passwords;
}
```

---

And here is my code for `PasswordResults` class.

```
public class PasswordResults {
    public int id;
    public String entryName;
    public String website;
    public String username;
    public String password;
    public String description;
}
```

---

Could be an easy fix like half the things I put on here but thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Please add the stack-trace from the log that should narrow down where the array is empty.

Comment: please post logcat

Comment: logcat please....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Odds on no rows are being selected by the `getSelectedPassword`. The do...while construct won't be entered (i.e. `cursor.moveToFirst()` returns false) and thus the result an empty ArrayList being returned that has no elements and thus index 0 is out of bounds.

Check the ArrayList's size and only attempt to get the password if the size is greater than 0. Perhaps Toast or something to indicate the error.

Obviously you then need to ascertain why the **id** being passed is not found, which will be the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

If your `id` is a String, you have to change `+id` inside your query to `+ '"' + id + '"'`, so it will be treat as a String.

```
String refQuery = "Select "+COLUMN_NAME+", "+COLUMN_WEBSITE+", "+COLUMN_USERNAME+", "+COLUMN_PASSWORD+", "+COLUMN_DESC+" FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+COLUMN_ID+" = "+ '"' + id + '"';
```